# Blue Light reduction for iPod touch?

Tags: display, ipod-touch, ios, night-shift

After speaking with a senior advisor at Apple, I have been informed by them that the Night Shift feature (and other iOS features in the 9.3 upgrade) are not available for Ipod touch 5th generation, which is frustrating, as there seems to be no available alternative.

I used to have a great app on my Ipod called F.LUX (which as only available if I jailbroke the Ipod). This app reduces Blue Light, and is what the new Night Shift app in iOS 9.3 is based on.

Since Apple has abandoned Ipod 5 support for many new features in iOS 9.3,   and does not support Night Shift on the iPod touch 5, are there any system wide apps that I can install that will protect my eyes at night by reducing blue light emissions?

Comment: If you spoke with a senior advisor at apple, I'm certain that you likely have much greater insight into why 5th generation hardware won't support the feature.  In general, Apple has no reason to withhold a compatible feature from a specific model.

Comment: its 32 bit thats why. It's truly unfortunate as there are still thousands of Apple users who still have Ipod 5s who could certainly benefit from blue light reduction.

Comment: @bmike if you believe side coding works for F.lux, please feel free to answer the question with the relevant information for myself and other users to go about doing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you manage to find the project file that you can sideload using Xcode on a Mac, you can get f.lux without jail breaking.

Comment: went with another device. Cheers